# How the regression method affects the smoothness of the ’regression curve’ when we used them as a smoothing method?

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning, linear-regression

The following Quizzes are the rough　translation (with minor modification) of Quizzes No.08 of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate (JSSC)" (See (ref 1) ).

**The correct answers by the JSSC  are as described below** (See the column named "**【The correct answers】**."  ).  However, I cannot imagine **how to achieve the correct answer**.

> **My Question:**
>
> - **(My Question 0)** Why can we smooth the graph of Fig 1 by using (Formula 1)or (Formulas 2) ?  Detail of this question is as described in the column named 【 Detail of My Question 0】.
> - **(My Question 1)** How to achieve the correct answer to the following Quizzes? : How the regression method affects the smoothness of the ’regression curve’ when we used them as a smoothing method?

Detail of the (My Question 1) are:

> **【 Detail of My Question 0】**
>   The following graphs in both Fig 2 and Figs 3 show the relationship between the time (month) and the count of high energy-charged particles. 
>   How can we get the relationship between time (month) and the number of particles from this regression method?  Curves, shown in  ① to ④ of Figs 2 (and Fig 3) show the relationship between time (month) v.s number of particles.  Is this the correct understanding that:
>
> - In the following (Quiz 1) and (Quiz 2), "the number of particles (y)" is
>     an explanatory variable, not an objective variable?
> - In the case of (Quiz 1) below,  ${\beta}_{i}$ that minimizes
>     (Equation 1) considered as ${y}_{i}$?
> - Although it was not specified in the original question sentence of following Quiz 1 and Quiz 2, do ${y}_{i}$ have to be arranged in chronological order? (Chronological order means Manners that increase $i$ as the time goes on.)
>
> If so, what are the advantages compared to the elementally smoothing method such as the moving average method?

---

> **Quizzes**
>   The following graph shows the count of the High energy-charged particles during the period from October 2000 to October 2018. Total 217 data ${y}_{i}$ (i=1,2,..., 217; These data are quoted at secondhand from the [OLU](http://cosmicrays.oulu.fi/#solar)) are plotted in this graph. **Answer the following (Quiz 1) and (Quiz 2).**
>   [image]
>   
> **Fig.1**
>   **(Quiz 1)** To recognize the characteristics of data, smoothing is performed by the **Fused Lasso method** using the following equation, and we set λ =500. (Hereinafter, the following formula is referred to as (Formula 1). )
>   [image]
>   
>   Then, **which one is the most appropriate graph as a result of above-mentioned smooshing?** Select the best answer from the following ① to ④.
>   [image]
>   **Fig.2**
>   
>   **(Quiz 2)** Refer to the abovementioned total 217 data ${y}_{i}$, 
>   **smoothing was performed using a method different from Quiz 1**. The result of this smoothing is shown in the following graph.
>   [image]
>   **Figs.3**
>   
>   **Corresponding to the the graph above (See Figs.3), which of the following formulas, ① to ④ is most suitable as a smoothing method?**(Hereinafter, the following formulas are referred to as (Formula 2-①), ...,and (Formula 2-④) , respectively.)Select the best answer from the following ① to ④.
>   [image]

---

> **【The correct answers】**
>  
>   The correct answers are opened to the public by the JSSC (Ref.1). **The correct answer of Quiz(1) is ④, and the correct answer of (Quiz 2) is ④.** (So the correct answer of both Quizzes are ④.)

**References:**
**(Ref1)**[Question No 8 of the exam of the "2019's semi-first grade of Japan Statistical Society Certificate](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/131cI4xXf-jUh2NtpmJBZY5uH-WVHsiil)(Written in Japanese.)

**P.S.**
I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One characteristic of the LASSO penalty of the form $+\sum_i |\alpha_i|$ is that the solution vector $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ tends to have lots of zeros. You can find explanations of this behavior in [many places](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151954/sparsity-in-lasso-and-advantage-over-ridge-statistical-learning/151960#151960).

Applying this statement to the first question implies the Fused LASSO encourages many of the $|\beta_{i+1} - \beta_i|$ to be zero. Which plot has many $i$ such that $\beta_{i+1} - \beta_i = 0$?

For the second question, the graph seems to be *piecewise linear*. Can you use the same reasoning to see why (4) encourages piecewise linear solutions? (Hint: if the $(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n)$ form a line, what is $\beta_{i+2} - 2 \beta_{i+1} + \beta_i$?)

Comment: Thank you for your Hints!!  Do you mean to think about moving averages or like?  In the (Quiz 2), the method using Formulas ① to ③ are inappropriate for smoothing?  Because In these cases, most betas goes zero?

Comment: Let me clarify my understanding:  For the case of (Quiz 1), ${\beta}_{i}$ that minimizes (Equation 1) considered as ${y}_{i}$? So $({t}_{i},{\beta}_{i})$ are plotted on Fig.2  and the penalty-term acts like a moving average? ( Please refer to the updated【My Question】column.) If so, I think I am reaching an understanding.

Comment: @BlueVarious The scatter plots are of the points $(i, y_i)$, whereas the line plots are of $(i, \hat{\beta}_i)$ where $\hat{\beta}$ is the solution to the optimization problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand completely.